# Broadcast UDP in Chrome Extensions

Tags: google-chrome-extension

How would you send a UDP broadcast from a google chrome extension?

I've looked at http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/trunk/experimental.socket.html but I'm unclear as to whether it can send a udp broadcast or if it is stable enough yet to be usable. Is chrome.experimental.sockets a viable solution?

Answer (score 0):

[Google Chrome Extensions (Labs)](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/experimental.html)

> **Caution**: Don't depend on these experimental APIs. They might disappear, and they will change. Also, the Chrome Web Store doesn't allow you to upload extensions that use experimental APIs.

Comment: Right. I was hoping for information about how far along the implementation is or, if thats not the right solution a pointer in the right direction because I am new to this and my googling hasn't turned up much. I am not concerned about the Chrome Web Store.